# VBA - Share an excel file with reference libraries included

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, reference, libraries

I am doing an automation VBScript on Excel with Selenium for web scraping. I downloaded SeleniumBasic from the site and it worked amazingly so far.

The problem is I have to send this excel file via email to My collegues, and they have 0 to none knowledge about programming or computers in general. So i would like to keep things simple for them: send the file and get them to use it inmediatly without having to install Selenium and the chromedriver.

Is there a way to do this? To have the excel sheet itself to include the added reference library (Selenium)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you are doing?

Comment: Are you putting the scraped data in excel and want to send the excel to them?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in the way you want. The PC you send it to needs to have the library installed, it's not something you can include in an excel file - excel only includes a reference to a library. The only way you could automate the process (or some of it) is by getting the VBA to actually download the DLL and install it for them, so the first time the user opens the file it'll do most of the work for the user.

Comment: The excel has to load information from the website i am scraping by using Selenium, so, i need selenium to be working from before, like jamheadart said.

Do you know a way i can install any library programatically? If you can help me with that , it will really help me :)